# How can I restrict AEM users to view and start specific workflow instances using AC Tool rep:glob in .yaml files?

Tags: permissions, yaml, workflow, aem, acl

I have the [Netcentric accesscontroltool](https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool) deployed on my AEM instance, and we are using it to set permissions for specific users to access specific workflow models and instances. While this is working correctly for models, I am having trouble allowing a user to only be able to start an instance of one specific model (Email Campaign Workflow). Here is my .yaml code (I have workflow permissions in /etc, /libs, and /var and /conf parent folders set already, so I'm excluding those to show only the relevant paths):

```
- path: /var/workflow/models/email-campaign
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: null

- path: /conf/global/settings/workflow/models/email-campaign
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: null

- path: /var/workflow/instances
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: ""

- path: /var/workflow/instances
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: /*/

- path: /var/workflow/instances
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: /*/*/

- path: /var/workflow/instances
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: /*/*/*/

- path: /var/workflow/instances
  permission: allow
  actions:
  privileges: jcr:read,jcr:lockManagemenet,jcr:versionManagement,rep:write
  restrictions:
    rep:glob: /*/*/email-campaign-workflow*
```

I'm able to see the specific instances in /libs/cq/workflow/admin/console/content/instances.html and in /libs/cq/workflow/admin/console/content/models.html, but when I try to start an instance of this workflow, I'm getting the following error in my Network tab in the console:

[image]
[image]

I'm pretty new at [rep:glob restrictions](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/security/authorization/restriction.html#Built-in_Restrictions), so if anyone could please let me know which extra permissions to add, that would be awesome.